# What is the order in which the bootup tasks are run?

Tags: linux, boot, bash, systemctl

I have a Debian 10 server and I'm running a systemctl service on it. I am using `systemctl enable myservice` to run it at startup. Also, I have a few lines of bash script, which help set up networking/port forwarding etc. for the service. I want that bash script run at startup. I'll be using [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/109104/how-can-i-run-shell-script-at-boot-start-up) to run it at startup. My question is, what is the order the things will be executed in? Will the bash script run first or the systemctl service? I have to make sure that the bash script runs first and then the service. Is it so by default? If not, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no order. In general, always assume that everything may happen in parallel and that there is no guaranteed order until you *request* one. (Although systemd has several bootup stages, both things you mentioned happen within the same stage.)

The rc.local script itself **is run as a normal service**. It requests to be run "after networking", but other than that, [doesn't](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-rc-local-generator.html) try to be placed in any specific position – so it *will* run parallel to other normal services.

Also, avoid rc.local. It always ends up being a dumping ground for bunch of different tasks that often have contradictory ordering requirements. Create separate services for all tasks that don't have a generic service yet. (You don't need a new service for /proc/sys – systemd-sysctl can handle that. You don't need a new service for iptables – iptables-persistent can handle that.)

*The answer you found was written in **2010** and the Debian boot process has [changed quite a bit](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_stage_4_the_normal_debian_system) since then. What made sense with the mostly-linear LSB/sysv init may no longer make sense with systemd, and vice versa.*

So there are two ways to ensure that your script runs before your (existing) service:

#### Separate services

Whenever you create new a service, you can use `Before=` or `After=` to explicitly ask for it to be sorted before or after something else, whenever both things are queued at once:

```
[Unit]
Description=Custom port forwarding configuration
Before=myservice.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/enable-port-forwarding.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### Part of an existing service

In case the task is 1) quick and 2) *very* specific to just one service, it can be run as an ExecStartPre= command within that service itself:

```
[Service]
...
ExecStartPre=/etc/enable-port-forwarding.sh
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myservice
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation...